# Regex: how to capture new line only if certain criteria are met?

Tags: regex, expression

I am looking to capture information line by line, but only if certain criteria are met. So in File A below, I can easily just look for 123, then look for 456 in the next line.

However, I am having trouble proceeding to capturing 789 in File B without releasing the match on file A. I am not sure how to tell regex "look for this in a new line, if it's there, capture the line. if it's not there, just stay on the current line."

How can this be accomplished?

File A:

123

456

File B:

123

456

789

Comment: How are you applying these expressions? Language, script, etc. Can you show us a sample of what you have so far?

Comment: What tool or language are you using, and please edit your question to be more clear as it isn't clear enough what you are asking ?

Comment: attach some code and tag with the programming language

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how to tell regex "look for this in a new line, if it's there, capture the line. if it's not there, just stay on the current line.

You could just match the new line as part of an expression repeated multiple times, e.g:

```
\d{3}(\n\d{3})*
```

Not sure of the specifics of exactly what you want to match but this is the best I could come up with without further info...